# Compound components: How to refer to the clicked child element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following React components.

```js
function Parent({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function MyChild({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent>
        <MyChild>text</MyChild>
        <MyChild>text</MyChild>
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to catch the clicked `MyChild` element in Parent component and attach a class to it. How do I do that without changing this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to eject properties to every `Parent` child:

```js
function Parent({ children }) {
  const ejectedChildren = Children.map(children, child =>
    cloneElement(child, { onClick: () => console.log('Clicked') })
  );

  return <>{ejectedChildren}</>;
}
```

[`React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) maps every child to a new element with additional `onClick` prop using [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

`React.Children.map` receives component `children` and a `mapping` function.

`React.cloneElement` receives a component and additional properties, then creates a new component with the new props merged in shallowly.

Demo:

[image: Edit Q-56620933-SO]

Another [example injecting to all tree](https://gist.github.com/denvash/a52dfa24eeac50a0a0ff7b2cfd0d8c7d).

Answer (score 1):

You could use React.cloneElement. eg

```
function Parent({ children }) {

  return <div>
    {React.Children.map(
      React.Children.toArray(children),
        (child) => {
          React.cloneElement(
            child,
            { onClick: () => { /** Do stuf */ } }
          )
        }
      )}
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
function Parent({ children }) {

  return <div>
    {children}
  </div>
}

function MyChild({ children ,handleClick}) {
  return <div onClick={handleClick}>{children}</div>
}

function App() {
  return <div>
    <Parent>
      <MyChild handleClick={() => console.log("hello1")}>text</MyChild>
      <MyChild  handleClick={() => console.log("hello2")}>text</MyChild>
    </Parent>
  </div>
}
```

Here is the demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-rubin-gxjrt . 
Although its not recommended way. I would suggest you to use context for this.